# How to get formatted word document's content using OpenXML?

Tags: c#, itext, openxml-sdk

I'm using this code for reading a word document's contents and save the content into a PDF file using iTextSharp library:

```
WordprocessingDocument wordprocessing = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, false);
Body body = wordprocessing.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
using (var pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4))
{
    var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream("Test.pdf", FileMode.Create));
    pdfDoc.Open();
    var fontPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SystemRoot") + "\\fonts\\tahoma.ttf";
    var baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    var tahomaFont = new iTextSharp.text.Font(baseFont, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
    var ct = new ColumnText(pdfWriter.DirectContent) {RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL};
    ct.SetSimpleColumn(100, 100, 500, 800, 24, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var item in body)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append(item.InnerText);
    }
    var chunk = new Chunk(stringBuilder.ToString(), tahomaFont);
    ct.AddElement(chunk);
    ct.Go();
}
```

everything is OK, but the document's content gets saved without any formatting. In fact I want to convert the document file with its format into PDF file. So my question is that How can I the content along with its format. As I mentioned I want the same result.
Any idea?

Comment: You only use the innerText of the body elements, none of its other attributes. Thus, obviously, you transport no formatting. You have to consider all the attributes to keep the format.

Comment: So, How can I transport the content with format?

Comment: Study the WordprocessingDocument API to know how all the formatting details are given in your source objects. Study the iTextSharp API to know how to put these attributes into your target objects. Implement. Depending on the details you want to copy this may take quite a number of weeks to implement.